# Disable the automatic selection of datagrid row using the mouse or keyboard

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, selection

In my sample project I have a datagrid that gets populated with values from the server. The datagrid row can be selected using the mouse initially. But in my code, this row selection should happen only after an "activate" button is clicked. How should I do this?

I tried the `IsEnabled` property for datagrid, but that causes the entire datagrid to be inactive
(the text and headers are grayed out).

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that should work:

```
datagrid.SelectionChanged += (obj, args) => 
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
    datagrid.UnselectAll()));
```

An alternative is modifying DataGrid styles. Anyway, you need to also consider your "activated" value.

Comment: Thanks @Darjan, it worked. Now on Clicking the "activate button" (its a toggle button) it should retain the orginal state(i.e datagrid rows can be selected). I tried with **IsHitTestVisible** setting to false. But ...:(

Comment: You only have SelectedItem property available. Property SelectedItems to set multiple selected items is not available, you would probably need to imlement it by hand in a custom control derived from DataGrid and use some logic to preserve previously selected items somewhere.